# java.io.FileNotFoundException for file R.java (R.java gets generated to wrong path)

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-resources, android-build

I have had a problem where R.java is being generated to a strange path when I build.  The path is as follows:

```
<App folder>\<App Name>\build\generated\source\r\<Flavor suffix>\debug\<ApplicationId>\<Flavor suffix>\R.java
```

To my knowledge the path should be only under the flavor suffix first and then under the applicationId, but as you can see from my example it is being generated under a second Flavor suffix.

Any help would be appreciated.  The exact error is as follows:
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':aiDx:generateY1DebugR2'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Workspace\Y1 - Test App\aiDx\build\generated\source\r\y1\debug\ait\com\aidx\y1\R.java (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: you getting error in build folder, try to delete build folder and run it again, if not working than go to android studio File->Invalidate Cache/Restart.

Comment: Hi @HemantParmar I have deleted the build directories and have run Invalidate Cache/Restart but I still get the same error.

Comment: try this rebuild project.

Comment: @Hemant thanks for the replies.  I have found the problem it was ButterKnife that was causing the issue.  I will post solution in answer.

Comment: ok, welcome and thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that gets this issue, Butterknife was causing this build problem.

The solution can be found here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1177